# How can I rewrite my URL from one format to another using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

This is my current url https://www.theenaija.com/?p=forum&id=13/barcelona-will-not-pay-liverpool-4-5m-should-coutinho-wins-ucl-with-bayern

How can I rewrite my url to this https://www.theenaija.com/forum/13/barcelona-will-not-pay-liverpool-4-5m-should-coutinho-wins-ucl-with-bayern?  I made attempted several coding solutions but none has worked for me; I need to do this for SEO purposes.

This is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)\&title=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/%1/%2?  [NC,L,R=301]
```

this is how i get my page

```
<?php 
          function getpages(){
            if(!isset($_GET['p'])){
              include_once("application/veiw/Home.php");
            } else {
              $get = @$_GET['p'];
              switch($get){
               // veiw post page
               case 'forums':
                include_once('application/veiw/veiw.php');
                break;
                case 'music':
                include_once('application/veiw/music.php');
                break;
                case 'lyrics-m':
                include_once('application/veiw/Lyrics.php');
                break;
                case 'video':
                include_once('application/veiw/Videos.php');
                break;
               //end of veiw post page
                  // END OF FORUM/TECH CATIGOLY
                default:
                  include_once('application/veiw/404.php');
                  break;
              }
            }
          }
          ?>
```

Comment: I modified your title and tags to emphasize that this is a programming question concerning the [tag:mod-rewrite] URL rewriting module and not a general SEO question.  As explained in [the tag help](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info), general SEO questions are off-topic here so you need to make sure that your question doesn't look like one.  A better title makes that clear.  See [ask].  Feel free to [edit] and correct any mistakes, though.